# I want to disable "the chrome is being controlled by automated test software" while executing any test in robot framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, chrome-web-driver, chrome-options

Is that possible to disable chrome banner"chrome is being controlled by automated test software" in robot framework..I saw there is many code available for java+selenium.. please help me to get the solution.

Tried maximum effort but failed

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to remove nor advisable to do that.